# JSON Jackson convert a field to nested field

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to convert a field to nested field while de-serializing from json.

```
class Person {

  private String name;

  private String salary;

}
```

The above object has to converted to below json value

```
{
  "name": "Nandha",
  "details": {
    "salary": 1000
   }
}
```

Could anyone help me on this!

Comment: Salary is string in the java code and here in the json string it is int. Is this intended ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a class named `Detail` to contain Salary etc? That's the easiest way. Or you could write a customer Deserialiser